# Как удалить markup без удаления сообщения Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

У нас есть 2 функции:

- 1. `(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):`

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    a = await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Кого ты ищешь?", reply_markup=gender_choose)
    data['msg_1'] = a.message_id
```

- 2. `(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):`

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(message.from_user.id, data['msg_1'],
                                        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

В первой мы отправляем сообщение с клавиатурой, получаем ответ `message` и записываем в `a`, для наглядности, `у` из `а` получаем `message_id` отправленного ботом сообщения, записываем в хранилище состояния для передачи в другую функцию.

Во второй функции бот должен отредактировать раскладку (мне просто нужно удалить клавиатуру без отправки лишнего сообщения с параметром `reply_markup`), мы передаем записанный ранее `id` нашего сообщения и....... получаем:

> aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited

Я не понимаю, почему невозможно отредактировать сообщение.
В документации есть строчка:

> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.

Если это распространяется и на редактирование раскладки, то выход только отправлять лишнее сообщение с `reply_markup=ReplyMarkupRemove()` ?

Comment: Какой тип маркапа в `gender_choose`?

Comment: ReplyKeyboardMarkup

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вы хотите удалить маркап, не делая новое сообщение, то можно удалить старое сообщение на котором висит reply_markup.
А еще я не понимаю почему вы просто на запихнете в стейт обьект Message, у которого есть метод `delete`. Это же значительно легче и безопаснее, чем удалять так как делаете вы.

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    msg = await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Кого ты ищешь?", reply_markup=gender_choose)
    data['msg_to_delete'] = msg

###
async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['msg_to_delete'].delete()
    # либо так без удаления старого сообщения
    data['msg_to_delete'].edit_reply_markup()
```